# Vue.js Parent Child communication via Props and Events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

[image: childParent]

Hello I am relativly new to Vue.js and sofar I enjoy working with it but today I am struggling and I have not found a clean solution for my problem.

I have 9 Child.vue components which I create in a v-for loop every Child.vue includes a ContextMenu.vue component. If I click on a button in Child.vue i trigger this context menu. Everything works well sofar.

Now I want only one context menu to be shown at every point in time. So i was thinking I emit a Event to the Parent.vue something like "menuIsShown" and dispatch in the parent a event to every Child.vue to hide the menu. In the one menu I could simply set it to visible.

```
 this.$emit('contextMenuShown', true);
 this.showMenu();
```

But as I learned there is no $dispatch in Vue2 any more. So i tried to use this.$children in the Parent.vue to trigger a method in every Child.vue. Somehow this did not work aswell and I guess there must be a better solution for this problem as you should use Props to communicate down to the children. But this seems pretty hard to me in a for loop. To use a global Event bus would be possible also, but is that really necessary?

Any best practice advice how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance 
robi

Comment: You want the other child components to hide when another child components' click event is triggered?

Comment: only the context menu in every child, to make sure only one contextmenu is shown at every point in time

Comment: 1) In the mount and unmount callbacks you could listen or stop listening for click events on `document` and hide the context menu when the event did not originate from the context menu root. 2) Have only one context menu in the parent and update its content according to the children.

Answer (score 1):

Vue have [one way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow), so data can be passed from parent to child via props. You can emit events from child to parent as documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events)

But given that you have many child components, I will recommend to use a central state machine, and [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) is a fine example of it which is quite popular as well in the community.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use [vue-clickaway](https://github.com/simplesmiler/vue-clickaway). This project is for this particular case where you want to listen to the clicks outside the component.

The use is pretty simple

```
import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway';

export default {
   mixins: [ clickaway ],
   template: '<p v-on-clickaway="away">Click away</p>',
   methods: {
      away: function() {
      console.log('clicked away');
    },
  },
};
```

I had used an `eventbus` when I had to do such a thing on my own. The eventbus is for such things where using a state could be overkill and emitting from each component might make it a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I ended up calling a Method on every child. 
I think this is the most logical way for me (I know there are several ways). Accessing the children is not very convenient, because I generate them in 2 nestet v-for loop. Not very elegant to access but it is working.

```
 var rows = this.$children[0].$children
      for(var j = 0;j<rows.length;j++){
        var row = rows[j].$children;
        for(var i = 0; i<row.length;i++){
         row[i].hideMenu();

      }


      }




  },
```

Answer (score -1):

In parent:

```
this.$children[index].$emit('contextMenuShown', true);
```

In children:

```
mounted () {
    this.$on('contextMenuShown', function() {
        // Do stuff
    });
}
```